# Hide gizmo for a given camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, components

I want to create a custom gizmo for camera in Unity - now I add CustomCamera script to gameobject with standard Camera existing.
For CustomCamera I can override OnDrawGizmos() function - but I need only one gizmo, not two (one for standard camera, and another for CustomCamera)
Also I don't want to collapse standard Camera component in the Inspector.

So, is there a way to switch off gizmo for a given Camera from script?

Here is the screenshot of what I want to do. There are 2 gizmos: linear gizmo for standard camera - and I want to hide it (red arrow), and spherical gizmo, drawn in OnDrawGizmos() function of CylindricalCamera - this gizmo is to be retained.

[Two gizmos screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbbO1.png)

If this is possible, I don't want to hide the stadnard camera from the Inspector, or collapse it in the Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/515484/choosing-which-camera-draws-gizmos.html

You can use `Camera.current` in `OnDrawGizmos` to check which camera is currently rendered. Simply perform a check, if you want to render Gizmos with that specific camera (e.g. use tags or a Property in your camera script)

**Edit**
You can disable standard gizmos in the gizmos dropdown menu. For the camera uncheck the box next to *camera*. (See screenshot)
[image]

Comment: That's not I am looking for. I'll explain my problem in more detail:

Comment: I want to hide a gizmo for standard component, not for MonoBehaviour. Even if I attach CustomCamera with empty OnDrawGizmos() function overriden, the standard Camera gizmo is still being drawn.

Comment: can you upload an image with which gizmos you want to hide, please?

Comment: Image uploaded to the question

Comment: Unchecking Camera in Gizmos menu will collapse all Cameras in the Inspector - I was trying not to do this... I think the proper way is to create Camera from script in CylindricCamera and set _camera.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector By doing this all that user can see is my CylindricCamera and I have to re-implement all fields in Inspector. Anyway, thanks!